# IntelliJ Idea: automatically remove unnecessary "throws" declarations

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide, automated-refactoring

Often after refactoring `throws` sections become unnecessary. IntelliJ highlights them with grey showing that they can be removed, but I'd like to remove them automatically (just like unused imports get removed via <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>).

**Q:** Is there a way to automatically remove unused `throws` sections within a class? Is there a shortcut for that?

Comment: You can remove all with backspace key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways I am aware of:

1. **[Quick Code Cleanup.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/specify-code-cleanup-scope-dialog.html)**

I use the <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> combination. There was no default hotkey.

[image]

You can specify code cleanup scope. It might be the whole project or a custom scope.

[image]

2. **[Removing the redundant clause.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/applying-intention-actions.html)**

It gets accessible on the focused clause (you put the mouse on the element) with <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>⏎</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Is there an automated CLI way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and select Cleanup code.

This will remove all unnecessary throws Exception declarations.